# asp-route-* not rendering query string inside view of view component

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this anchor tag helper inside a view component:

```
<a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Signup" asp-route-xxx="xxx" asp-route-returnUrl="/">Sign Up</a>
```

When it gets rendered in the browser, it looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't pass in the asp-route-* that I added. But the exact same tag helper I copy and pasted on a controller view, it gets rendered like this:

[image]

It contains the asp-route-* values in the query string. Do I need to do something to make it work for ViewComponents?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with asp.net core 2.1 viewcomponent, but it generates the link correctly with query string.